# Age until physical growth ceases, mammals

Tags: mammals, growth

Fairly basic, but I am seeking a table showing how many years from birth it takes for the best-known mammals to stop growing.  (Including the latest on humans - ie. 0-17..?).

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE!  This is a very broad question and it isn't clear what you mean by "best-known" mammals. The answer is also going to depend on environmental factors (e.g. nutrition) and what parts of the body you consider — consequently even an answer limited to humans is going to be difficult and probably not definitive. ——— Please take the time to go through the [tour] and then the help pages starting with [ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: You might need to construct the table to match the conditions & assumptions you need.

Comment: I only meant what you could call gross height in humans, say.  Ie, total height!  The same for other mammals, ie, top of head from the ground.  Other hominids, apes, chimps...  Elephants ..?  Nothing too esoteric, perhaps 30 or so examples, preferably closest to humans, whether taking longer or shorter periods to fully grow than we do.